# Geocode intersecting streets using geocoding webservice api

Tags: web-services, api, geocoding, intersection

Hi from sunny South Africa

We are using the Google Geocode Webservices API to obtain lat/long for street addresses. This works perfectly well using a single street. Is there a way to specify a second street (intersecting street) in the Geocode HTTP Request using the Geocode Webservices API?

```
Example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,***+Intersecting+Street***,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false
```

Found a working solution:

Using the words "CORNER" and "AND" before and between the intersecting streets respectively seems to derive the desired results. Not extensively tested, use at own peril. Example:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=CORNER%20Rooihuiskraal%20AND%20Ruimte,%20Centurion,%20Gauteng&sensor=false
```